# Wireless device bug on 13.10. BCM4313 registers as eth1 instead of wlan0 and no internet access

Tags: wireless, broadcom, adhoc

My Hotel WiFi requires me to login with a user name & password after connecting to the hotspot. So, my browser would open a page with user name & password fields to login and then connect to the Internet.

But unfortunately, Firefox & Chromium don't seem to work. I don't think it is browser related but a setting for the WiFi router or driver which is creating this issue.

Using Broadcom 801.11 STA wireless driver (proprietary). Tried open source as well but same result.

The image linked below shows my WiFi connection setting & Chromium. The login page itself comes up after a long time and after entering the credentials, it keeps loading for ever. It's the same for every other browser. So I don't think it's a browser issue but something to do with WiFi setting or network manager stuff.

Interestingly, I am able to connect to WiFi networks using WPA without any issue. Adhoc hotspot is a problem and that is my regular home network. I hope I can get some help solving this issue!

I have tried repeating the same hotspot after login from my android, by creating a virtual repeater with WPA key and it works. I can browse on Ubuntu using this method but cant be doing this regularly! I tried loading the same login page of the hotel WiFi while browsing through my repeater WiFi created on the mobile and attached a screen shot below. The page loads up quick and easy. Does this means something is wrong with the way network manager handles adhoc connectivity & login?? I installed wicd0 but it crashes on startup and is not helpful at all!

`ifconfig` output is:

```
krishna@krishna-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig eth0      Link
encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:92:4a:1d:54:fa  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:e6:89:fa:49  
          inet addr:10.24.1.71  Bcast:10.24.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fe89:fa49/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:348431
          TX packets:6611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7669631 (7.6 MB)  TX bytes:864195 (864.1 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:166120 (166.1 KB)  TX bytes:166120 (166.1 KB)
```

I wonder why is the wireless configured under eth1? I think this is a bug with earlier Ubuntu versions, but is this normal in 13.10 or is there a wrong configuration here?

The wireless device in my pc is **BCM4313** and I have installed the bcmwl-kernel-sources, wireless-tools to support the device. I also reinstalled the bcmwl-kernel as suggested on broadcom website, via synaptic package manager.

Nothing has changed this situation!

I tried booting into a LiveUSB and then `ifconfig` results show the wireless under wlan0. But then the wireless connects and loads the login page. So is the problem with the device configuration now?

I really want to get this fixed before I start configuring the other stuff like ATI graphics and such on the laptop for overheating. Lack of Internet access is too bad a bug for me. Any help is appreciated!

pastebin of dmesg:
[dmesg](http://pastebin.com/LPxzGnCM)

lsmod of my pc:

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
acpi_call              12714  0 
nvram                  14462  0 
joydev                 17575  0 
uvcvideo               82247  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40903  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  28326  0 
videodev              139144  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14269  0 
intel_powerclamp       19031  0 
coretemp               17728  0 
kvm                   457676  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       14250  0 
crc32_pclmul           13160  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55720  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13294  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            14095  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
parport_pc             32866  0 
cryptd                 20501  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
ppdev                  17711  0 
bnep                   23966  2 
rfcomm                 74658  12 
bluetooth             391597  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
hp_wmi                 18202  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41684  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      55098  1 
snd_hda_intel          57183  3 
snd_hda_codec         194881  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13613  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               107140  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30465  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                66061  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
fglrx                7500792  144 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              30038  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i915                  734026  2 
microcode              23650  0 
psmouse               104113  0 
snd                    73802  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
rtsx_pci_ms            18320  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
drm_kms_helper         53165  1 i915
memstick               16762  1 rtsx_pci_ms
drm                   303133  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 18418  0 
lpc_ich                21163  0 
mei                    78609  1 mei_me
soundcore              12680  1 snd
amd_iommu_v2           19198  1 fglrx
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 i915
wmi                    19363  1 hp_wmi
dm_multipath           27371  0 
scsi_dh                14873  1 dm_multipath
arc4                   12573  2 
hp_accel               26012  0 
lis3lv02d              20280  1 hp_accel
brcmsmac              564467  0 
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
video                  19574  1 i915
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
mac_hid                13253  0 
bcma                   51651  2 brcmsmac
mac80211              634700  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              504229  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
lp                     17799  0 
parport                42481  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
mmc_block              36316  2 
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23920  0 
ahci                   30063  3 
libahci                32088  1 ahci
r8169                  73111  0 
rtsx_pci               46133  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    13981  1 r8169
dm_mirror              22326  0 
dm_region_hash         20981  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18527  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror


krishna@krishna-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -v 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev
 09)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus
 master, fast devsel, latency 0     Capabilities: <access denied>

 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core
 processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0   Bus: primary=00,
 secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0    I/O behind bridge:
 00003000-00003fff  Memory behind bridge: 60000000-60ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000040000000-000000004fffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: pcieport

 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
 processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus master,
 fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46     Memory at 61000000 (64-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=4M]    Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, prefetchable)
 [size=256M]    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]     Expansion ROM at
 <unassigned> [disabled]    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver
 in use: i915

 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus master,
 medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41   Memory at 61700000 (64-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=64K]   Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
 driver in use: xhci_hcd

 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210
 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)   Subsystem:
 Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895    Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
 latency 0, IRQ 45  Memory at 61714000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
 [size=16]  Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: mei_me

 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus master,
 medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16   Memory at 61719000 (32-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=1K]    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
 driver in use: ehci-pci

 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)   Subsystem:
 Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895    Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
 latency 0, IRQ 47  Memory at 61710000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
 [size=16K]     Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use:
 snd_hda_intel

 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0   Bus: primary=00,
 secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0    I/O behind bridge:
 00002000-00002fff  Memory behind bridge: 61600000-616fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000061400000-00000000614fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: pcieport

 00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0   Bus: primary=00,
 secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0    Memory behind bridge:
 61500000-615fffff  Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in
 use: pcieport

 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset
 Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus master,
 medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23   Memory at 61718000 (32-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=1K]    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
 driver in use: ehci-pci

 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC
 Controller (rev 04)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0     Capabilities: <access
 denied>    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

 00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA
 Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
 Device 1895    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ
 44     I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]  I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]  I/O ports
 at 4080 [size=8]   I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]  I/O ports at 4060
 [size=32]  Memory at 61717000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: ahci

 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family
 SMBus Controller (rev 04)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
 1895   Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10    Memory at 61715000 (64-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=256]   I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]

 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
 [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA
 controller])   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Radeon HD 7670M
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48   Memory at 40000000
 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]     Memory at 60000000 (64-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=128K]  I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]    Expansion
 ROM at 60020000 [disabled] [size=128K]     Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

 07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 Device 5289 (rev 01)   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42   Memory at 61600000
 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]  Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci

 07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895  Flags: bus master,
 fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43     I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]    Memory
 at 61404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]   Memory at 61400000
 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

 08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn
 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
 Device 1795    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17   Memory
 at 61500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities:
 <access denied>    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

blacklist.conf

```
krishna@krishna-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
 # This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
 # alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
 # device instead.

 # evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly blacklist evbug

 # these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred blacklist usbmouse blacklist usbkbd

 # replaced by e100 blacklist eepro100

 # replaced by tulip blacklist de4x5

 # causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces blacklist eth1394

 # snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
 # hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810) blacklist snd_intel8x0m

 # Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device) blacklist snd_w2

 # causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306) blacklist i2c_i801

 # replaced by p54pci blacklist prism54

 # replaced by b43 and ssb.
 #blacklist bcm43xx blacklist wl

 # most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565) blacklist garmn_gps

 # replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721) blacklist asus_acpi

 # low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
 # hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969) blacklist snd_pcsp

 # ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
 # nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010) blacklist pcspkr

 # EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
 # from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
 # continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
 # really needed. blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on a laptop with the same wireless network card, which functions well. So, let's start digging...

My advice is not to use the STA propriety driver, but the open source brcmsmac. This should be included in recent kernels.

As you said and as I can see in your screenshot, your WiFi setting is set to Ad-hoc. I believe that should be instructure.

Let's compare some results.

```
lspci -v

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e042
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at c4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-f5-ff-ff-7b-84-4b
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

What kernel are you using? I'm using a mainline kernel, however, it has been working with the Ubuntu kernel out-of-the-box with 3.8, 3.10, and 3.11 too.

```
uname -a

Linux AOD270 3.12.0-031200-generic #201311031935 SMP Mon Nov 4 00:36:54 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If the brcmsmac driver is installed correctly lsmod should give this.

```
lsmod | grep brcm

brcmsmac              564467  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              634700  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              504229  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
bcma                   51651  2 brcmsmac
```

In /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf I have a couple of broadcom modules blacklisted. Check if you have these blacklisted too and if not, try what happens if you add these and reboot.

```
# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# Disable the recently enabled b43 module (kernel 3.11?) - manually added
blacklist b43
```

I have no bcmwl packages installed.

```
arthur@AOD270:~$ dpkg -l | grep bcmwl
arthur@AOD270:~$
```

My result of ifconfig

```
arthur@AOD270:~$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:4b:f5:7b:df:31  
          inet addr:192.168.1.51  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46448 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46071 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25717517 (25.7 MB)  TX bytes:10768286 (10.7 MB)
```

Hopefully this helps you on the right path to find the cause.
Did any of the above help to resolve your problem?

Comment: I tried making the connection as infrastructure instead of ad hoc, but no difference in the behavior. I can not load the login page yet.

Comment: It looks like you have installed two networking managers, network-manager and wicd. Is that correct? If so, try to remove one of the two, to prevent conflicts. And since network-manager is default to Ubuntu, remove wicd.

Comment: The command lsmod | grep brcm returns nothing but lsmod | grep bcmwl returns ii bcmwl-kernel-source.   6.30.223.141+bdcom-Ubuntu 1 ....May be because I don't have any open source driver for this driver, but only proprietary wl drivers..I'm using 3.11 kernel...so if open source drivers are working, how do I get my device to use those instead?   I have removed the wicd and now have only one network manager which comes as default

Comment: Try blacklisting the bcmwl modules in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, and then reboot. Also, type 'dmesg' and see if you can find a useful message there regarding your wireless driver(s).

Comment: Maybe it is better to try unloading the bcmwl driver on the fly and loading the brcmsmac driver, before blacklisting. Unload by "modprobe bcmwl -d" or "modprobe wl -d" and then load the broadcom driver by "modprobe brcmsmac"

Comment: Dmesg returns huge error log saying the message: [6469.811748] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_getstation: wrong mac address....this is the only message and it fills the window

Comment: Modprobe bcmwl -d says option requires an argument

Comment: Give the unloading and loading of drivers a try. Once you found the right setting, you can make it fixed by blacklisting the unwanted drivers. I have to go now to pick somebody up. Keep me up-to-date of your progress.

Comment: That means it cannot find the module (= driver), probably the name of the driver is different, such as wl.

Comment: I did modprobe wl and then modprobe brcmsmac...no change in ifconfig or connection... modprobe wl -d says again the same ...modprobe: option requires an argument -- 'd'

Comment: Ohw shoot, I see a mistake, and it's mine. I'm sorry. The unload command is not modprobe -d, but modprobe -r. So try modprobe -r b43 and modprobe -r wl. Once unloaded try to load with modprobe brcmsmac. Any positive change?

Comment: Hi arthur.. I have removed wl and b43 using modprobe -r and then installed new drivers by modprobe brcmsmac... then I verified this step by lsmod| grep brcm and I could see brcmsmac in the list. After this, ifconfig shows me wlan0 for wireless.. but Wi-Fi Issa not working... It doesn't even scan for new wireless networks !

Comment: Okay, one down, more to go. :-) Did you uninstall wicd? Maybe it is  conflicting with network-manager? "sudo apt-get remove wicd" or "sudo apt-get purge wicd" (to delete wicd including the settings).

Comment: I did to reboot to live usb and checked now that the situation is very similar to my installation... Wi-Fi is not working even in live boot...My guess is then the brcmsmac are not the correct drivers?... btw I don't have wicd installed on my Ubuntu installation...I only have Wi-Fi radar app installed to search and connect the strongest signal

Comment: I hate to ask this... do you have a hardware switch on your laptop, to turn on/off the Wifi card? Sometimes it is a real switch, sometimes is a keycombination (like Fn+F3). Maybe your wifi card is turned off....

Comment: it is a key combination and is turned on.. I did one more small experiment in the meantime.. I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 daily and boot to it. I could connect to wifi and also load login page. I did some browsing and i clicked on install 14.04. Then checked all the boxes to search for updates etc while installing and puff.... my wifi gets disabled & re-enabled.. this time i go to terminal & check with lsmod.. i find wl, which was not there earlier. So this brings me to conclusion that a similar thing happened when i installed 13.10.. removing wl & add bcm/brcm must help !

Comment: Manually unloading wl and loading of brcmsmac works? If so, you can probably blacklist wl and maybe brcmsmac will be loaded automatically on boot.

Comment: And can you attach the following to your post? "dmesg", "lsmod", "lspci -v", "cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"

Comment: Your suggestion to edit blacklist.conf with wl after modprobe has helped me fix the issue. I have also updated the kernel before this step. Now i have stable connection over WiFi.. thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Nothing worse than not having Internet :D

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're refering to 802.11 adhoc standards. In which case, they're slower than normal wifi protocols. Let me rephrase that. They're dauntingly slow. I was thinking of setting up a neighborhood Adhoc network but it was horrible with Adhoc protocols. The best adhoc network you can setup would be WDS with OLSR protocol.